# How can I test a function that takes an array and outputs 3 random elements?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, random, jestjs

I want to test this function using Jest. The problem is that I don't know how I can write the test without adding all the possible outcomes in the toBe(). Any hints are welcomed.

```
const options = [1, 2, 3, 4]
 const getElements= (options) => {
  const getRandomEl = (list) => list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];
  return [
    getRandomEl(options),
    getRandomEl(options),
    getRandomEl(options),
  ];
```

And here is my test:

```
describe("Helper tests", () => {
    test('We should get 3 random elements from a list', () => {
      expect(mathOperations.getElements([1, 2, 3, 4])).toBe([1, 2, 3] | [2, 3, 4] | [1, 2, 4]); //how to avoid adding all possible combinations in the toBe()?
    });
   })
};
```

Comment: Do you realize that `[1, 2, 3] | [2, 3, 4] | [1, 2, 4] === 0`?

Comment: Maybe install [the extended Jest toolset](https://jest-extended.jestcommunity.dev/docs/matchers/array/#toincludeanymembersmembers).

Comment: maybe you can test that the returned array contains exactly 3 elements and that each element is included in the input array. If it fits your case, you might also test that the returned array does not contain duplicated items.

Comment: @secan There's nothing that prevents duplicated items in that code.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot test that a single array matches multiple arrays. That is, `[1, 2, 3] | [2, 3, 4] | [1, 2, 4] === 0`.

As suggested by @Andy, you can test that the output array only has members from the initial array using [`toSatisfyAll`](https://jest-extended.jestcommunity.dev/docs/matchers/array/#tosatisfyallpredicate)

```
const list = [1,2,3,4];    
test('We should get 3 elements from a list', () => {
  expect(mathOperations.getElements(list).length.toBe(3);
});

test('We should get random elements from a list', () => {
   expect(mathOperations.getElements(list)).toSatisfyAll((el) => list.includes(el));
});
```

Having said all this, I think `const getRandomEl = (list) => list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];` is the function that makes more sense to be tested since its name is actually meaningful whereas `getElements` doesn't to much besides calling `getRandomEl` and adding that three times to an array.